# c#.net Webbrowser control Anchor Tag Invoke Click event not work for alternate rows

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I am using c#.net and webbrowsercontrol.
I am invoking click event of anchor tag.

Application has following code:

```
HtmlElementCollection anchors = browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");
foreach (HtmlElement anc in anchors)
   { 
   if(anc.GetAttribute("href").ToLower().Contains("javascript:PFA".ToLower())
      {
       anc.InvokeMember("click");
      }
   }
```

It works for one row and not for the other row.
Source Website has following :

```
                            <td colspan="1" id="tdborder" align="left" width="5%">
                            <input  name="appsWithStatusChg" type="checkbox"   id="appsWithStatusChg1" alt='checkBoxLabel1'
                            label='checkBoxLabel1' 
                            value="12114831" >
                            </td>                       


                            <td width="10%">

                            <a class="PairLink" tabindex="17" href="javascript:postForApplicationData('12114831')">
                            12/114,831



                            </td>
                            <td width="10%"> -</td>
                            <td width="14%"> US 2008-0209452 A1</td>
                            <td width="14%"> 1133-112US02</td>
                            <td width="11%"> 98449</td>
                            <td width="9%"> 12-24-2011</td>
                            <td width="17%"> 05-05-2008</td>
                            <td width="8%">




                            <!--<input type="button" name="submitForIFW" value="Review" id="submitForIFW" onClick="postForIFWData('12114831')" tabindex="9" >
                            -->
                            <a href="javascript:postForIFWData('12114831')" tabindex="9"> View</a>




                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

Problem is that when we try to invoke click event 
for anchor tag whose tr is wpsTableShdRow is not working. 
anchor tag whose tr is wpsTableNrmRow is working.

when we try to access click event manually it works.

Comment: can you provide your full code and the source document?

Comment: I would not recommend using GetElementsByTagName(...). It functions differently across browsers.

Comment: Please provide full code. As what ever code you have shown here is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
HtmlElementCollection anchors = browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");
foreach (HtmlElement anc in anchors)
   { 
   if(anc.GetAttribute("href").Contains("javascript:postForIFWData('12114831')"))
      {
       anc.InvokeMember("click");
      }
   }
```